# Props passed as array is getting as object type in the child component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In my ReactJS application my `ParentComponent` is calling a child component by passing some `props` into it as

```
<ChildComponent val={["a1"]} sets={{}} />
```

Inside my `ChildComponent` I have given some console to check props that are receiving and found as

```
const ChildComponent = ({val, sets}) => {
    console.log("val", typeof(val))
    console.log("sets", typeof(sets))
    return <p> Hello </p>
}
```

But in the console I got as

```
val object
sets object
```

Why I am getting the array passed as props is getting as object when I check the type?

Comment: The typeof an array is an object. In JavaScript, arrays are technically objects; just with special behaviours and abilities. For example, arrays have a Array.prototype.length property, which will return the number of elements in the array. More Info : https://bitsofco.de/javascript-typeof/

Answer (score 0):

Because beneath the surface the array is object (wired right), i.e. if you `console.log(typeof [])` will be `object`.

So the useful check for it would be:

```
var isArr = val instanceof Array;
var isArr = Array.isArray(val);
```

But the most reliable way is:

```
const isArray = Object.prototype.toString.call(val) == '[object Array]';
```

Comment: Does `Object.prototype.toString.call(val)` support in very  older versions of browsers? or which will support older versions also?

Comment: @Hareesh it does. In-fact, it is one of the oldest ways of keeping check on arrays intact.